# Increment an array from a sub class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to increment my array for each character that is found in a text file, but when I try to increment the array using either +1, +=, or ++ I get a message saying "Operator '++' cannot be applied to operand of type 'CharacterFrequency'." I also cannot use int[] for this either.

Thank you in advance in any guidance you can give.

```
string s = File.ReadAllText("wap.txt");
CharacterFrequency[] count = new CharacterFrequency[(int)char.MaxValue];

foreach (char t in s)
{

   count[t]++;
}
```

The expected result would be for the array to hold a occurrence of each unique character from the text file. Such as `count[] = {A, a, B, c }`.

My CharacterFrequency class:

```
class CharacterFrequency
{
  public int Frequency { get; set; }
  public char Char { get; set; }

public override string ToString()
{
  return $"Character: {Char} Frequency: {Frequency}";
}
```

Comment: `CharacterFrequency` is not an int. How does that class look?

Comment: I added my second class as you asked.

Comment: Why are you using an array to store a value to increment, cant count just be an int?

Comment: No, sadly my teacher is requesting me to use the CharacterFrequency[] instead.

Comment: So you want to count the number of times each unique character appears in the file? or you need to return each unique character that appeared in the text file?

Comment: I need to do both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously your problem is you need to add the Frequency reference:

```
count[t].Frequency++;
```

However, since this is academic, you could also do this with Linq.

Advantage, you only have a list of chars in that file, and still fairly efficient:

```
var count = File.ReadAllText("wap.txt")
                .ToCharArray()
                .GroupBy(x => x)
                .Select(x => new CharacterFrequency() { Char = x.Key, Frequency = x.Count() })
                .ToArray();

foreach (var item in count)
   Console.WriteLine($"{item.Char} {item.Frequency}");
```

or

```
var dict = File.ReadAllText("wap.txt")
               .ToCharArray()
               .GroupBy(x => x)
               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

foreach (var item in dict )
   Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} {item.Value}");
```

---

**Additional resources**

[File.ReadAllText Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Opens a text file, reads all the text in the file into a string, and
> then closes the file.

[String.ToCharArray Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Copies the characters in this instance to a Unicode character array.

[Enumerable.GroupBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Groups the elements of a sequence.

[Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Creates an array from a IEnumerable.

[Enumerable.ToDictionary Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Creates a Dictionary<TKey,TValue> from an IEnumerable.

[$ - string interpolation (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

> The $ special character identifies a string literal as an interpolated
> string. An interpolated string is a string literal that might contain
> interpolated expressions. When an interpolated string is resolved to a
> result string, items with interpolated expressions are replaced by the
> string representations of the expression results.

Comment: Linq expressions are an example of fluent interface. It's an interesting concept for making code more readable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C#

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do this:

```
string s = File.ReadAllText("wap.txt");
int[] count = new int[(int)char.MaxValue];

foreach (char t in s)
{
   count[t]++; // or count[(int)t] ++;
}
```

**Updated code:**

You can declare an array of your objects like this:

```
CharacterFrequency[] count = new CharacterFrequency[(int)char.MaxValue];

for (int i=0;i < count.Length; i++)
{ count[i] = new CharacterFrequency();}
```

then you can do this:

```
foreach (char t in s)
{
   count[t].Frequency ++;
}
```

Final code. there are 128 ASCII characters:

```
CharacterFrequency[] count = new CharacterFrequency[128];

for (int i=0;i < count.Length; i++)
{ count[i] = new CharacterFrequency();}

foreach (char t in s)
{
    if (count[t].Char == '\0')
    {
        count[t].Char = t;
        count[t].Frequency = 1;
    }
    else count[t].Frequency++;
 }
```

Comment: For my assignment my teacher doesn't want me to use an int array. Sorry I should have mentioned that.

Comment: When initializing the array with CharacterFrecuency objects, don't forget to initialize the property Char, I believe with: as Char = (char)i

Comment: now I ran into one problem which I'm confused about. When I ran this it created an infinite loop, but following the process of how the foreach should work I don't understand why.

Comment: char.MaxValue = 65535 I believe. so, it will take a while initializing the array

Comment: you can change it to CharacterFrequency[] count = new CharacterFrequency[128];
for 128 ascii characters

Answer (score 0):

You need to access and increment the `Frequency` property:

```
count[t].Frequency++;
```

Note that you have an array of `null` values at the moment, so you should initialize each item in turn before attempting the above code, otherwise you'll get a `NullReferenceException`.

`count[0] = new CharacterFrequency();` will instantiate the first item.